# Which is correct, 静かだったばかり or 静かばかりだった to mean "It was just quiet, that's all"

Tags: grammar

I'm a bit confused about how I turn 静かなばかり (It is only quiet) into "It WAS only quiet".

Answer (score 3):

"It is only quiet" can translate to 「静かなばかり｛だ/です｝」, 「静かなだけ｛だ/です｝」, or 「ただ静か｛だ/です｝」 etc.

So, to turn the sentence into the past tense, all you have to do is turn the assertive auxiliary (or copula) だ/です into the past form, like this:

> 「（ただ）静かなばかり｛だった。/ でした。｝」
>   「（ただ）静かなだけ｛だった。/ でした。｝」
>   「ただ静か｛だった。/ でした。｝」